# Spark History Server Authentication in Kerberized Cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, kerberos, hortonworks-data-platform

I set-up a HDP cluster which contains amongst others Spark. I also enabled Kerberos for the cluster, so that all services and users have to authenticate via their principals.

This seems to work fine, all services are running, and an user has to get a valid Kerberos ticket before he can access e.g. the YARN ResourceManager's Web UI.

Else he gets an error message like this:

[image]

However, after making a `kinit` the website is accessable by the user.

What I now want to do (I thought it already is), is to secure also the Spark History Server UI like that, so that a user has to authenticate via Kerberos ticket. Actually everyone can access the UI without authentication:
[image]

Is there a possibility to do this at all? If yes, how can I configure this?

The actual permissions on the `spark.eventLog.dir = hdfs:///spark-history` are `777`. Here a screenshot of the Ambari HDFS view:
[image]

Comment: This question, while interesting, seems a bit broad for the SO format.  Can you narrow a bit?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution to this in [IBM's documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSPT3X_4.2.5/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.admin.doc/doc/admin_spnego_iop_services.html)

You re-use Hadoop's jetty authentication filter for Kerberos/SPNEGO `org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter`

You can do this by setting in Spark's default.conf
`spark.ui.filters=org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter`
and
`spark.org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.params=
type=kerberos,kerberos.principal=${spnego_principal_name},kerberos.keytab=${spnego_keytab_path}`
Be careful with those replacement variables, they didn't work for me when setting these values in Ambari. Also consider adding `cookie.domain` and `signature.secret.file` similar to the other Hadoop SPNEGO-configurations.

Obviously this only works when the Spark History Server runs with the Hadoop-classes in its classpath -- so it's not an out-of-the-box solution for a SMACK-stack for example.