# Kerberos Authentication via JAAS context fails when system user != principal user

Tags: java, authentication, kerberos, jaas, principal

I need to authenticate against a Kerberos Realm with the user `test`. I want to do this by creating a secure JAAS context via a corresponding `jaas.conf` config file:

```
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  doNotPrompt=true
  principal="test@MYREALM.DE"
  useKeyTab=true
  keyTab="/home/ubuntu/kerberos_test/test.keytab"
  storeKey=true;
};
```

The `krb5.ini` file contains the information about the Realm and the Kerberos servers:

```
[libdefaults]
  default_realm = MYREALM.DE

[realms]
  MYREALM.DE = {
    admin_server = my.server.de
    kdc = my.server.de
  }
```

And here the Java Code of my Application, which authenticates against the Kerberos Realm and prints the directories in `/` of my HDFS:

```
public class KerberosAuthentication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String webHdfsUrl = "webhdfs://my.server:50070";
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.defaultFS", webHdfsUrl);
        conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");

        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        FileStatus[] fsStatus = fs.listStatus(new Path("/"));

        for(FileStatus status : fsStatus) {
            System.out.println(status.getPath().toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the code with the following arguments (in Eclipse or as `java -cp ...jar`):

```
-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/home/ubuntu/kerberos_test/krb5.ini 
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/ubuntu/kerberos_test/jaas.conf 
-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=true
```

I get the following results:

- System username == Principal username (`test`): Everything works fine, I get an output of the root directories of my HDFS
- System username (e.g. `ubuntu`) != Principal username (`test`), I get the following exception:

Exception output:

```
java.io.IOException: Usernames not matched: name=ubuntu != expected=test
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.toIOException(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.access$600(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:98)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.shouldRetry(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.runWithRetry(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:652)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.access$100(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:472)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner$1.run(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:502)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.run(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.listStatus(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:1330)
    at kerberos.KerberosAuthentication.main(KerberosAuthentication.java:31)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): Usernames not matched: name=ubuntu != expected=test
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.validateResponse(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:374)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.access$200(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:98)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$AbstractRunner.runWithRetry(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:623)
    ... 8 more
```

How can I authenticate with `test`, if my system user is another one? Is there a possibility to add some settings to the `jaas.conf` or the Java code?

Comment: But I provide the keytab of the "test" user, a normal "kinit" via console also works fine, also when I do it with another user, e.g. userB.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that one....

Comment: For the problem scenario in this case, are all the components running in the same network as in your other question from Jan 12th of this year?:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41608019/spark-history-server-authentication-in-kerberized-cluster

Comment: From the error stack it's clear that it's an **Hadoop issue**, not a Kerberos issue *per se*. What are you connecting to: the NameNode directly? an HttpFs service? a Knox gateway?

Comment: Please Google for `hadoop kerberos "Usernames not matched"` and figure out what kind of configuration mistake you've done...