# How to enable spark UI security

Tags: security, user-interface, apache-spark

I have followed following link to secure spark UI.
http://lambda.fortytools.com/post/26977061125/servlet-filter-for-http-basic-auth

Then exported the job as jar and put it into spark's jars directory. I have also made change in spark-defaults.config like below,

`spark.ui.filters        sparkauth.SparkBasicAuth`

`spark.test.SparkBasicAuth.params user=foo,password=cool,realm=realmname`

but when I tried to start the spark master, getting error,

`17/12/01 13:48:40 INFO JettyUtils: Adding filter: sparkauth.SparkBasicAuth
17/12/01 13:48:41 ERROR MasterWebUI: Failed to bind MasterWebUI
javax.servlet.ServletException: No user provided in filter configuration
        at sparkauth.SparkBasicAuth.init(SparkBasicAuth.java:66)`

Need help.

Comment: Can you explain why you used this config key: `spark.test.SparkBasicAuth.params` To me it looks like that's not getting parsed.

Comment: I am not sure about this, I just wanted a way to pass parameters to servlet but it seems it is not passing those. I am not getting what should be the the exact key and its value.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Kerberos, since it allows for passwordless authorization, see this question and answer:
[Spark History Server Authentication in Kerberized Cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41608019/spark-history-server-authentication-in-kerberized-cluster/47592978#47592978)
This also means you are not as obligated to use SSL for the connection. Plaintext passwords are essentially the absence of security, so you might as well skip http-basic-auth unless using HTTPS -- and even then it's more like Pseudo-authentication.

Comment: I tried kerberos in Hadoop authentication but I got some difficulties there and that is still pending. So for Spark I thought it better to have another approach. Anyways I will check this also.

Comment: HTTPS is not required when using Kerberos?

In 2017, SSL is no longer a question. It is a standard and should be enabled <period>

There are attacks against Kerberos ticket too: https://blog.stealthbits.com/complete-domain-compromise-with-golden-tickets/

Comment: Yes, there are, but they are far less trivial than clear-text password intercepts ;) -- I'm not advocating not using SSL - but for Spark 1.6 (which still makes up a large percentage of the code base) for example, SSL encryption for UIs simply isn't available.

Comment: @Rick Moritz, can I use kerberos for spark standalone mode? Because I read that it only supports spark with yarn mode and I have stand alone cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Posting another answer, since my initial answer was ethically correct, but not the actual answer to the question.

Assuming you use the example code verbatim
You set

`spark.ui.filters` to `com.fortytools.servlet.BasicAuthFilter`

and

`spark.com.fortytools.servlet.BasicAuthFilter.params` to  `user=foo,password=cool,realm=realmname`

Then you have a long hard think, about what you're actually doing here ;)

Comment: I can to able to enable authentication for Spark master UI. Initially I was using key `spark.test.SparkBasicAuth.params` which should be `spark.sparkauth.SparkBasicAuth.params`. Thanks!